# How to remove an element prefix in a soap message

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have to send an xml content into soap message.

The web service rejects the request because there is an extra prefix in the root element of the body.

The generated soap message is :

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
    <ns3:rootElement xmlns:ns2="http://webserviceprovider/result" xmlns:ns3="http://webserviceprovider/request">
    --- other data 
    </ns3:rootElement>
</S:Body>
```

What is expected by the web service is a soap message without prefix (ns3):

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
    <rootElement xmlns:ns2="http://webserviceprovider/result" xmlns:ns3="http://webserviceprovider/request">
    --- other data 
    </rootElement>
</S:Body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The expected XML seems wrong to me. You have to specify from which namespace do the elements come from and from the looks of it, you do not specify any default namespace, hence the prefix.

Comment: I agree with you, but the service provider expected this XML.

Comment: In that case you will probably have to edit the XML manually, since JAS-WS will not generate this as its wrong.